# two div toggle with two links

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have two div which initially hide. when i click on link 1 first div open and when i click on link 2 second div open. but they close other open divs.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#agent, #agency").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $(".show_hide_two").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){$("#agent").slideToggle();});
    $('.show_hide_two').click(function(){$("#agency").slideToggle();});

});

</script>


<div id="agent">Agents</div>
<div id="agency">Agency</div>
```

Comment: which other open divs ? u have only two divs in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what your after?

Use slideUp to hide what you dont want

```
$("#agency").slideUp();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j3PFE/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at thi [How to swap content div using link buttons?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-swap-content-div-using-link-buttons/) link this will help you to get the answer for showing div based on the link is clicked.

```
$("#div1").slideDown();
$("#div2").slideUp();
```

i hope this will help you more.